# How to find the penultimate digit

Tags: python

I have to find the last digit and the penultimate digit of some number. I know how to find the last but not the penultimate digit. (i am the only beginner)

```
a = int(input('Enter a minimum two-digit number '))

b2 = a % 10
b1  = 

print('Penultimate digit is: ', b1)
print('Last digit is: ', b2 )
```

Comment: You mean penultimate *digit*?

Comment: Just a side note: before calculating the digits, check whether the input really has at least two digits. Print a meaningful output if the input doesn't match the requirements instead of doing calculations on false assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Treat your input as `string`, then get its `-2` index.
Python's negative index mean index start from the end (-1 is the last, -2 is penultimate, -3 is the item before it ...)
One last thing, what you want is *digit*, not number :D

```
a = input('Enter a minimum two-digit number ')

print('Penultimate number is: ', a[-2])
print('Last number is: ', a[-1] )
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, but you could simply take the remainder modulo 100, then take the result of the integer division by 10:

```
 1234 % 100 // 10
 # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the two last digits, you could either convert to a string and get the last 2 characters:

```
>>> '4321'[-1]
'1'
>>> '4321'[-2]
'2'
```

or use arithmetics. You first need to extract the last 2 digits with `% 100`:

```
>>> 4321 % 100
21
>>> 21 % 10
1
>>> 21 // 10
2
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are other - faster - solutions, you may reuse what you already found out:

From `a` subtract its last digit (you got that already) and you'll get a number with a trailing 0, which means it's divisible by 10. Now divide that by 10 to remove the 0. Now the last digit (and you know how to obtain that) is the penultimate digit of the input number.

```
b1 = ((a - b2) / 10) % 10
```

Now we can simplify that again: Instead of first making `a` divisible by 10, you can also use [floor division](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html):

```
b1 = (a // 10) % 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted the number into an array and then decreased 2 from the length.

Steps
1.Convert number into array
3.Find penultimate index subtracting array.length - 2
4.Use index to return penultimate digit

```
function splitIntoArray(number) {
  numArray = Array.from(String(number), Number);
  return numArray;
}
```

```
function getPenultimateDigit(num) {
  arrayNum = splitIntoArray(num);
  penultimate = arrayNum.length - 2;
  digit = arrayNum[penultimate];
  return digit;
}
```